# Constructor being called with less arguments in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I have class Foo with a constructor as given:

```
class Foo {
 public:
   Foo(int w, char x, int y, int z);
   ...
 };

int main()
{
   Foo abc (10, 'a');
}
```

Can I use that constructor like this? When constructor signature do not match?

**So How do I give default value?**

Comment: What have you tried? What is your stumbling point? Which diagnostic did you find hard to understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not unless the parameters at the tail of the signature have defaults, for example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int w, char x, int y=5, int z=0);
    ...
};
```

If there are defaults, then you can supply only the non-defaulted parameters, and optionally some defaulted ones, i.e. any of the following invocations would be valid:

```
Foo abc (10, 'a');
Foo abc (10, 'a', 3);
Foo abc (10, 'a', 42, 11);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, unless the missing constructor arguments have default values.

For example, you *can* do this:

```
class Foo {
 public:
   Foo(int w, char x, int y = 0, int z = 1);
   ...
 };

int main()
{
   Foo abc (10, 'a'); /* y is implicitly 0 and z is 1 */
}
```

Comment: or unless constructor overload.

Answer (score 1):

To provide default parameters, equal them to zero or else with some default value.

```
class Foo {
 public:
   Foo(int w, char x, int y = 0, int z = 0) { }
   // ...
 };
```

Or,

```
class Foo {
 public:
   Foo(int w, char x, int = 0, int = 0);
   // ...
 };

// Define your constructor here, note 'no default parameters'
Foo::Foo(int w, char x, int y, int z) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

No - if there is no constructor which accepts two arguments with matching types, you can't.

Comment: So how do I give default value?

Comment: Change your _declaration_ of the ctor to `Foo(int w, char x, int y = 10, int z = 10);`. Do not change the _definition_ (the place where you write the code itself).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to overload the constructor rather than providing default values.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int w, char x); // y = 0, z = 1
    Foo(int w, char x, int y); // z = 1
    Foo(int w, char x, int y, int z);
};
```

It's a matter of style in the end: cons you need to duplicate the initializer list, because constructors cannot be chained, pros readability IMHO. Make sure to read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187640/default-parameters-with-c-constructors).