# C++ : Function overloading vs Variadic function vs Variadic template vs default parameter

Tags: c++, performance, function, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have seen these questions:

- [Overload a method or use default values? c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876590/overload-a-method-or-use-default-values-c)
- [function overloading vs default argument in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284952/function-overloading-vs-default-argument-in-c)

but they do not consider variadic functions and variadic template .

Consider the problem of writing a function to find the average of either 2 or 3 positive numbers .

There are four ways we could implement this function:

1. Using a default parameter:

   ```
   int average(int x , int y , int z=-1);
   ```
2. Using function overloads:

   ```
   int average(int x , int y);
   int average(int x , int y , int z);
   ```
3. Using a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

   ```
   int average(int x,int y, ...);
   ```
4. Using a [variadic template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)

   ```
   int sum=0;
   int count=0;
   void average(){
      return;
   }
   template <class A, class ...B> void average(A argHead, B... argTail){
      sum =sum+argHead;
      count+=1;
      average(argTail...);
   }
   ```

What are the pros and cons of using one method over another ?

Comment: 3 is not type-safe. And choosing between 1 and 2 depends on what the functions are doing.

Comment: As you can see all of them have to solve same problem .

Comment: Also, for number 3 you don't really know how many arguments there are, and you need to manually fetch the arguments from the stack and convert to the correct type (while hoping that the user passed correct values).

Comment: Regarding 1 and 2, for just this specific use-case, for 1 you have to keep a special case inside the function to check for `z` being `-1` and not use the variable in that case. With method 2 you don't need any special cases.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are providing differences not pros and cons .

Comment: I would argue that lack of type-safety and not knowing the argument count are definitive cons, as is the use of special cases. My suggestion is that you implement all three, see which one you like best, and then do performance testing on them.

Comment: Agree for 3rd case but what about 1 and 2 case ?

Comment: Why do you think he highlights differences rather than "pros and cons"? Because they are different and suited for different use cases :). Furthermore, in the first case, what would happen if I do `average(9,1,-1)`? I'ld get `5` instead of `3`  as my last number would be ignored.

Comment: @Rerito It has been mentioned that find average of only +ve numbers .They all works in same way except putting some extra logic and extra code but there may be some pros of using one above another that i would like to now .

Comment: Then write the word in _full letters_, I read the `+ve` as a typo...

Comment: "array should not be used". I'm curious as to why this stipulation, if you don't mind my asking.

Comment: What about a variadic template?

Comment: @Taekahn just for fun . If we can pass array there is no need of these three types we can just write a single function and done.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg pity to close this, it's a lovely question imo. Too broad, heck yeah, so what. There are far too many narrow and narrowminded questions on SO. Only issue one could have: it may be better suited over in codereview.

Comment: @PeterSchneider can you move to codereview section ?

Comment: I flagged it for moderator review because I (or any normal user., I think) cannot move it. I also read in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89799/how-to-migrate-to-code-review that one criteria for suitability in codereview is "Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?"; I think you presented example code, which may be considered OT in cr, which apparently tries to be a review site for "real code", whatever that is.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thanks . Yes this is a example code . Actually i was doing my assignment where i need overload a function with one extra  arguments (both function were doing same thing except one extra `print statement` based on third argument ) then i thought let's see which one could  do better since we can achieve same thing in different way .

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints, namely average of either two or three positive numbers, the second option is the best.

The first option, with the optional argument, requires a test for positivity:

```
int average(int x,int y,int z=-1) {
    if (z<0) return (x+y)/2;
    else return (x+y+z)/3;
}
```

In term of providing the service of finding an average, that test is unnecessary. Further, it is brittle: it's reasonable to consider finding the average of numbers that could also be negative, and this solution is not compatible with that case.

The third option, the variadic function, is inappropriate because you will need to provide information in the call to indicate how many arguments are present, e.g. with a terminating negative number, or with the first parameter indicating the number of remaining arguments. This complicates the interface. Further, it is not type safe, and the burden then rests on the users of the function to be scrupulous in calling it only with `int`s — the compiler will not prohibit or warn about incorrect usage.

Using a variadic template is a good, general solution that extends easily to any number of parameters. Here though, we need only the two and three argument cases, and so it's overly complex for the application. If you were to use this though, you'd want to use a different implementation that did not require global variables. The following uses a namespace to hide some of the implementation details, and forces the use of `int` arguments by fixing the head type before the recursion:

```
namespace impl {
    int sum() { return 0; }

    template <typename... V>
    int sum(int a,V... rest) { return a+sum(rest...); }
}

template <typename... V>
int average(int a,V... rest) {
    return impl::sum(a,rest...)/(1+sizeof...(V));
}
```

Comment: I think n_arg exists out of the box as `sizeof...`, cf.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024304/c11-number-of-variadic-template-function-parameters

Comment: Well, there you go — I've learnt something new and useful, thanks! Will update answer to suit.