# How to declare object of a class without passing parameter to its Constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a class with its constructor having a parameter. Now I had to declare class A object. But I need to call the constructor later. But if I do that, I get the error.

e.g.

```
class A{
        public:
        int a;
        A(int x){
                a=x;
        }
};
int main(){
        A a;
        a=A(3);
}
```

Error

```
temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
temp.cpp:10:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
temp.cpp:10:4: note: candidates are:
temp.cpp:5:2: note: A::A(int)
temp.cpp:5:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
temp.cpp:3:7: note: A::A(const A&)
temp.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Why can't you just initialize with a dummy integer and overwrite it later with the real value?

Comment: This is not possible. The *constructor* is used for *construction*. Not for calling later.

Comment: You can't do `a=A(3)` as default visibility in C++ classes is `private`, thus uncallable outside the class. As for calling later,if for some reason you need object to be created at certain point of time (order on stack?) and initialized later (dependant on other objects?) you may move initializing code out of a constructor to some init member function.

Comment: Provide a default constructor such as `A() {a=0;}` and a copy constructor `A(const A &r) {a = r.a;}`. Best of luck.

Comment: This seems like a logical error, you CONSTRUCT a new object, if it allows assignment or another method to change it's value, you can do that.  If you're constructing a new object, just do that and you can use scope to have old one be reclaimed, if you need to recycle the memory.

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk "You can't do a=A(3) as default visibility in C++ classes is private" does not describe this situation. It is perfectly correct to call A(3), which will create a separate instance of the class, which then can be copied to a variable of this class if the class has an assignment operator.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh Well, my bad - I didn't notice indented `public`.

Comment: [`std::unique_ptr<A> p;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), and reset situationally to the A you want later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only good solution here is to avoid this situation arising in the first place.

The situation typically arises when you have something on the general order of having to create an object where its initial value depends on some condition, so conceptually what you want is something on this general order:

```
if (xyz)
    A a(123);
else
    A a(456);

// code that uses A goes here
```

The problem in this case is that in this case, `A` goes out of scope before you can use it. The cure is typically to divide this code up into two functions, so you end up with something like this:

```
if (xyz)
    code_that_uses_A(123);
else
    code_that_uses_A(456);
```

Although I certainly prefer to avoid it, there is another possibility that *can* be workable: a wrapper object that keeps track of whether the object it contains has been initialized or not. For example, it can contain a pointer to the actual object. This is initialized to a null pointer. When you initialize the object it contains, you allocate a contained object. Depending on what you want, attempting to re-initialize the container object could throw or it could just assign a new value to the contained object.

Of these two, the former is nearly always preferable. It tends to clean up the code and give each individual piece of code a single, clear responsibility. The latter can work, but generally requires quite a bit of work to get the wrapper object present a clean interface. Although I'd usually consider it a lesser concern, such a wrapper typically adds substantial overhead to using the wrapped object.

Comment: Why not `int i; if (xyz) i=123; else i=456; A a(i)`? But if the if statement is going to be that simple, you might as well use the ternary operator: `A a(xyz ? 123 : 456)`

Answer (score 2):

The very point of the constructor with parameter is to ensure that no object of the class may exist without a initialised. You cannot "call constructor later". You may add another constructor though, without parameters.

Comment: Exactly, the class member functions maintain the class invariants, a constructor ensures a *new* object is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you define an object. constructors get automatically called. What you may have as below:

```
class A{
  int a;
 public:
  A(int x = 0){
    a=x;
  }
  A(const A&arg) {a = arg.a;}
  A& operator =(const A&arg) {a = arg.a;return *this;}
};
int main(){
  A a;
  a=A(3);
  return 0;
}
```

Constructors may also have default arguments, so `A a;` might actually be implemented as like a call to constructor `A(0)` See  [Default parameters with C++ constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187640/default-parameters-with-c-constructors)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you have defined a constructor for A class which takes int as an argument. 
As you have defined your own constructor, compiler will not define default constructor for your class.

```
A(int x)
{
        a=x;
}
```

When you call:

```
A a;
```

This will look for a constructor for A class which does not take any argument. But that is not present. Thus the compilation error is coming.

Answer (score -1):

You should initialize any instance of a class. There is no way to have a "dummy" variable in no well-defined state, unless your class has a constructor without arguments.

Or, add a constructor with no arguments.

Note that assignment in `a = A(3)` calls an assignment operator on `a`.

Comment: No, a = A(3) calls the assignment operator

Comment: Right. Changing my answer.

Comment: The whole point of constructors for a class, is SO every object created maintains the class invariants and is thus in some defined state.

Comment: Care to explain why downvoted? I said the same: that no object can be created without constructor in no well-defined state. What's wrong with it? Of course a constructor with no arguments (default constructor) should also leave the object in a well-defined state. Please explain what's wrong with my answer.