# Why the default constructor is not initializing the variables?

Tags: c++, object, oop

When  `B b(0);` is called I am expecting it to call the default constructor to initialize protected data member data_ but it is showing error.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(int)’
candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Similar is the case for `D d(1, 2);`.

```
no matching function for call to ‘D::D(int, int)’
candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
protected: // Accessible to child
           // Inaccessible to others
    int data_;

public:
    // ...
    void Print()
    {
        cout << "B Object: ";
        cout << data_ << endl;
    }
};

class D : public B
{
    int info_;

public:
    // ...
    void Print()
    {
        cout << "D Object: ";
        cout << data_ << ", "; // Accessible
        cout << info_ << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    B b(0);
    D d(1, 2);
    //b.data_ = 5; // Inaccessible to others

    b.Print();
    d.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

What should I change to correct this?

Comment: "_I am expecting it to call the default constructor_": A _default constructor_ is by definition a constructor that can be called _with an empty argument list_. Why do you expect `B b(0);` which has a non-empty argument list (`0`) to call a default constructor?

Comment: What do your learning material, books, tutorials or teachers say about constructors and object construction with arguments?

Comment: "_What should I change to correct this?_": Define appropriate constructors accepting one and two arguments respectively.

Comment: Hard to be sure since you have snipped possibly relevant code but it seems you misunderstand what a default constructor is.

Comment: this might make things clearer about default constructors in C++: [Default parameters with C++ constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187640/default-parameters-with-c-constructors). And this should also be of use to you [Default constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor). Good luck.

Comment: `// ...` -- Why did you remove the most important parts of the code?  Your question has to do with constructors, yet you removed them.  It's like saying "something is wrong with my car", but we are not supposed to look at the car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default constructor is one that can be called without arguments like `B()` or `D()`. Where it defined with default argument B(int data=0) or empty B() where default value of `data_` will be default of `int` type . Constructor you call is user defined (with params `B(int)` or `D(int,int)`) while user forgot to define it. Each class responsible for new variable it introduces so constructor of `D` and `B` should be:

```
B(int data) :data_(data) {};
D(int data, int info) :B(data), info_(info) {}; //on data you call constructor of B since B added data_ variable
```

Your `Print()` should be `virtual` in B and must be `overridden` in `D`